# Turning a list into a diagonal matrix

Tags: python, matrix, pca, svd

I have a list of singular values as a result of an SVD of a data matrix. Python outputs as a list rather than the diagonal matrix. Combining the matrices to find regression coefficients is then impossible without turning the singular values into a diagonal matrix.

Simply, here is what I have:

```
U, W, Vt = np.linalg.svd(Absorbance_Data)
print U.shape, W.shape, Vt.shape
```

Output:

```
(71, 71), (71,), (512, 512)
```

I need to get matrix W to become a (71, 512) diagonal matrix (zero values allowed) in order to compute the regression coefficient for PCR.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It turns out you can use np.diag to generate diagonal matrix, but I'd like to add on 441 columns of 0-values.

Answer (score 0):

You first diagonalize `W`, then append the zeros:

```
W = np.diag(W)
W = np.append(W, np.zeros(71, 441), axis=1)

print(W.shape)
=> (71, 512)
```

This appends a 71x441 array of zeros to the 71x71 diagonalization of `W`. The `axis=1` appends the zeros columnwise.